# Django RF, error validating objects owner (error: Field 'id' expected a number but got .AnonymousUser )

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a object created by a user, When other users try to access the object, it should not allow it. I expect Django to throw error as `you are not authenticated`
After logging out, when anonymous user try to access the object Django throw error as mentioned below.

ERROR

```
TypeError at /PoUserTracking/
Field 'id' expected a number but got <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x0445F160>.
```

VIEWS.PY

```
class PoUserTracking(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = NewPoSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthor]

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Po.objects.filter(user=user)
```

PERMISSIONS.PY

```
class IsAuthor(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        
        return obj.author == request.user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check whether the user is authenticated or not first

```
from rest_framework import permissions


class IsAuthor(permissions.IsAuthenticated):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return self.has_permission(request, view) and obj.author == request.user
```

Comment: Thanks Abu, regards Sarbath Shameer

Answer (score 0):

just make request.user.id  //this will be solved for sure..